# Heroku Rails app crashing without indication of error (console works, dev environment works)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Please I need your ideas of what could be wrong with this Rails app on Heroku. The logs don't show any errors. Also, the Heroku console is fully functional, so I believe I can rule out an issue with the database or initializers. And the same app has no problem on my local machine. I even deployed a version that was working earlier today and it still gives "App crashed". What could be the matter?? How do I even start to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku is crashing for new deploys: [link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=36129190)